# Computing a probability distribution on a manifold

Tags: probability-distributions, manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be an invertible differentiable function. Let $Z=(Z_1,Z_2)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous random variable, where $Z_1\in \mathbb{R}^l$ and $Z_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{n-l}$ are independent. I'll denote its density (wrt the Lebesgue measure) by $p_Z(z)=p_{Z_1}(z_1)p_{Z_2}(z_2)$. I am interested in the distribution $p_X$ of $X=f(Z_1,0)$. I thought of two different ways of obtaining it, but they do not match. I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong. I will denote the support of $X$ as $\mathcal{S}:=f(\mathbb{R}^l\times\{0\})$.

The first way is as follows: Let $g:\mathbb{R}^l\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ be defined as $g(z_1)=f(z_1,0)$. Then, $X=g(Z_1)$. Furthermore, $g$ is bijective and differentiable, so we can use the change of variable formula to obtain the distribution of $X$: $p_X(x)=p_{Z_1}(g^{-1}(x))|J_g^T(g^{-1}(x))J_g(g^{-1}(x))|^{-1/2}$, where $J_g$ is the Jacobian of $g$ and by $|A|$ I mean the absolute value of the determinant of $A$. Furthermore, $J_g(g^{-1}(x)) = J_f(g^{-1}(x),0)(I_l,0)^\top$, so that $p_X(x) = p_{Z_1}(g^{-1}(x))|(J_f^\top J_f)_{ll}|^{-1/2}$, where $(J_f^\top J_f)_{ll}$ is the $l\times l$ submatrix of $J_f^\top J_f$ formed by the first $l$ rows and columns.

The second way is considering $X':=f(Z_1,Z_2)$ and computing $p_{X'|Z_2=0}$, which should be equal to $p_X$ since $X=X'|(Z_2=0)$ in distribution. To compute this conditional distribution, consider $h:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$, defined by $h(z_1,z_2)=(f(z_1,z_2), z_2)$ where $\mathcal{M}=\{(f(z_1,z_2), z_2)\in\mathbb{R}^{2n-l}:(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$. Again, $h$ is differentiable and bijective, so once again we can use the change of variable formula. We have that $J_h = (J_f^\top, 0, I)^\top$, so that $J_h^\top J_h = I + J_f^\top J_f$ . Then: $p_{X'|Z_2=0}(x)=p_{X',Z_2}(x,0)/p_{Z_2}(0)=p_Z(g^{-1}(x), 0)|I + J_f^\top J_f|^{-1/2}/p_{Z_2}(0)=p_{Z_1}(g^{-1}(x))|I + J_f^\top J_f|^{-1/2}$, which doesn't match the previous result...